# Running queries in MongoDB for data extraction

Tags: mongodb-query

I am trying to extract data from a DB in Mongo by running queries in RoboMongo to have data for have the data of one specific user, but the query I wrote dose not work. Can anybody help me with the mistake/s I'v made. Here is the query:

db.getCollection('restaurants').find({

```
"user" : "auth0|5845e0a768022a5112b0d51c",
"provider" : "fitbit",
"data" : {
    "activities-steps-intraday" : {
        "datasetType" : "minute",
        "datasetInterval" : 1}
}})
```

Comment: "Does not work" is pretty useless as a description of your problem. Add error messages if you have any, and/or describe the difference between the desired output and the output you're getting.

Comment: it says 0 record extracted but I can see data which has for example the ID I mentioned in the query. and my desired output is data belong to specific user from "fitbit" device.